# Can a state have zero periodicity?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

I am getting my concepts cleared in Stochastic process. 
I understand the concept of periodicity. Just to make it clear, suppose there is a finite Markov chain with states $1,2,3$. Let their transition probability matrix be 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
                    0 & 1 & 0 \\
                    1& 0 & 0 \\
                    0& 1& 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

In this case, what is the periodicity of state 3?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Answer (score 2):

I assume it is a self-study type of question, so here is a hint-answer.

Check the definition of periodicity carefully (from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Periodicity)):

> A state $i$ has period $k$ if any return to state $i$ must occur in
>   multiples of $k$ time steps. Formally, the period of a state $i$ is defined
>   as
>
> $$ {\displaystyle k=\gcd\{n>0:P(X_{n}=i\mid X_{0}=i)>0\}}$$
>
> provided that this set is not empty. Otherwise the period of a state $i$ is not
>   defined.

Then, using your transition matrix, compute $P(X_n = 3 | X_0 = 3)$ for any $n$, and see where the definition takes you.